# How to convert resulted thresolded image in picturebox to 8bbp pixel format

Tags: c#, image-processing

How to convert resulted thresolded image in picturebox to 8bbp pixel format?
I tried this code, but it not worked?

```
Bitmap orig = new Bitmap(thresholded);
            Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(width , height , System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed );
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone))
            {
                gr.DrawImage(orig, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
            }
```

The error is "A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format."

I need your assistance with this.

Comment: the error is "exception was unhandled"

Comment: You need much smarter code to know how to build a palette with only 256 colors and still get a decent result.  Rather pointless today btw, this stopped mattering 20 years ago.  Rumor has it that FreeImage has credible converters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google produced this answer

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/edd45c87-366c-4af8-a6fe-8ba9b1ffb002/a-graphics-object-cannot-be-created-from-an-image-that-has-an-indexed-pixel-format?forum=csharpgeneral

> An indexed image is an image with a palette.  GDI+ doesn't support drawing to indexed images.  Draw your indexed image on a non-indexed image and then draw your text on the non-indexed image:

```
  Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bm.Width, bm.Height);
  Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);
  graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
```

Comment: The question is how to convert the resulted image in picturebox to 8bpp?